# How much computing power does it cost to run GPT-3?

Tags: gpu, gpt

I know it cost around $4.3 million dollars to train, but how much computing power does it cost to run the finished program? IBM Watson chatbot AI only costs a few cents per chat message to use, OpeenAI Five seemed to run on a single gaming PC setup. So I'm wondering how much computing power does it need to run the finished ai program.

Comment: This is a programming/hardware issue, so it's off-topic here. Please, read https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. This question is maybe more appropriate for Data Science SE.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question but this is also interesting in this context: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/i49jf8/d_biggest_roadblock_in_making_gpt4_a_20_trillion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't anwser your question on how much computing power you might need, but you'll need atleast a smallgrid to run the biggest model just looking at the memory requirments (175B parameters so 700GB of memory). The biggest gpu has 48 GB of vram 
 I've read that gtp-3 will come in eigth sizes, 125M to 175B parameters. So depending upon which one you run you'll need more or less computing power and memory.
 (https://lambdalabs.com/blog/demystifying-gpt-3/) 
For an idea of the size of the smallest, "The smallest GPT-3 model is roughly the size of BERT-Base and RoBERTa-Base."

Answer (score 1):

I think it is premature to answer your question as OpenAI has not made GPT-3 available yet other than via a web-based API.  For more information see [OpenAI API](https://openai.com/blog/openai-api/).

From [OpenAI will start selling its text-generation tech, and the first customers include Reddit](https://www.theverge.com/2020/6/11/21287966/openai-commercial-product-text-generation-gpt-3-api-customers), by James Vincent:

**Access to the GPT-3 API is invitation-only, and pricing is undecided.**

You can join the OpenAI wait list here: https://beta.openai.com/

I read somewhere that to load GPT-3 for inferencing requires 300GB if using half-precision floating point (FP16).  There are no GPU cards today that even in a set of four will provide 300GB of video RAM.  For example, the best I believe you can do in a single desktop box is four NVLinked Nvidia RTX 8000 cards on a single motherboard.  Each card has 48GB of VRAM each.  That would only provide a total of 192GB of VRAM.